# Does any terminal support \r (carriage return) and \b (backspace)?

Tags: terminal, posix, tty, termcap, terminfo

I wrote nice `PS1` formatter:

```
PS1='\n===============================================\r$?|\u@\h \w \nbash# '
```

which shown prompt like:

```
0|user@desktop ~/devel/emacs ===================================
bash#
```

I use trick with `\r` to return cursor to the first line position, so output goes over `====...` like string.

Does any terminal support \r (carriage return) and \b (backspace)?

Do I need to query for support in `termcap` / `terminfo` if `isatty()` return true?

I see `\r` usage in *wget* / *curl* / *git* / *hg* / etc when utility shown progress.

Also `\b` is used when application shown progress sequence in single rotating position:

```
while true; do for x in '|' '/' '-' '\'; do printf '\b$x'; sleep 1; done; done
```

**NOTE** Please don't post images with type machines. Think about modern hardware or software emulators.

Comment: Because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity

Comment: Technically, you ask whether any terminal supports \r and \b, so there only needs to exist one such terminal to answer "yes".

Comment: Some guaranties can come from historical background, traditions, standards, coding practices that I don't aware of. So it is possible to answer positively to question. Or bring example of valuable terminal (like xterm) which lack asked support.

Comment: For the record, OSX Terminal and Putty support both `\r` and `\b`.